# Dropdown nav appearing behind video in the slider

Tags: css

On this site http://litecheck.mscreativelabs.com/ the drop down Nav is appearing behind the video in the slider in IE, Chrome, and Safari.

Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because the youtube video

add wmode to the param and it will be ok

```
<param name=wmode value="transparent">
```